# Return result of python script in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline where I have 2 stages:

```
pipelien {
  agent {label 'master'}
  stages ('stage 1') {
    stage {
      steps {
        sh "python3 script.py" //this script returns value {"status": "ok"}
      }
    }
    stage ('stage 2') {
      // Do something with the response JSON from script.py
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that I cannot do it. What I have tries:

1. Pass the result to an environment variable, but for some reason Jenkins didn't recognize it. Maybe I did something wrong here?
2. Playing an parsing stdout of script.py is not an option, because this script prints lot of logs

The only option which is left is to create a file to store that JSON and then to read that file in the next step, but it's ugly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably refactor the Python script to be something implemented native to Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean to use Groovy? Unfortunately, this is not a option, because we don't have such libraries in JVM (an SDK of a specific service)

Comment: @Aladin why do you consider writing the result into a file and then reading it an ugly solution? it is a generic approach that can then be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: Well, it took me some time to realize that it might be the only "clean" solution we have because we are talking here about different processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we chose to create files and store the messages there.
We pass the file name as an argument to python script and log everything.
We then remove all the workspace after the job succeeds.